# KNN classification data

Tags: excel, dataset, knn

Good day, i have a question, how can i define the feature matrix and labels from such data(screenshot)? I have data of 30 graphs, which consists of 1604 rows for each one. Fist 10 x,y columns - first class, 10-20 - second class and etc.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfHH4.png).

Well, the main problem is to align all 30 graphs data into X_train matrix. I thought of code which is below, but it' a wrong idea to Write all 30 matrix like that.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('Forest_data.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1')
data.head()
features1 = data[['x1', 'y1']]
```

As I think, my lable matrix should look like [0,0,.....1,1,....2,2,2...2]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.